# font error when using mapnik generate_tiles.py

Tags: mapnik

`generate_tiles.py` has worked fine throughout the transition from mapnik 0.7 to mapnik 2.x in gentoo linux.  Now I have switched to debian (wheezy) and I am getting the following error when I run `generate_tiles.py`:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to find font face 'unifont Medium' in FontSet 'book-fonts' in map '.../osm.xml'
```

If I comment out the book-fonts section in fontset-settings.xml.inc, I get:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to find font face 'unifont Medium' in FontSet 'bold-fonts' in map '.../osm.xml'
```

However, using tilelite creates the tiles just fine.

```
$ ls `python -c "import mapnik2;print mapnik2.fontscollectionpath"`
total 9048
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 2014-10-11 09:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root   4096 2014-10-11 20:48 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 611212 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 672300 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 580168 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 631992 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 576004 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 643852 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 345204 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 235848 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 313856 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 241972 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 333636 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSansMono.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 611556 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 720012 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSans.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 332036 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 341072 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 331128 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSerifCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 316440 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 338140 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSerifCondensed-Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 330012 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 338776 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 363200 2011-02-27 07:37 DejaVuSerif.ttf
```

No book font, but there are bold fonts.

These are all the dejavu fonts installed (with their version numbers):

```
ttf-dejavu                                          2.33-3   
ttf-dejavu-core                                     2.33-3    
ttf-dejavu-extra                                    2.33-3
```

I've seen a few people having this problem around the web, but no solutions offered.

Comment: apt-get install unifont Just worked for me

Answer (score 0):

*unifont Medium* (lowercase) is replaced by *Unifont Medium* (uppercase) with recent Ubuntu or Debian versions.

One solution is to remove/change the *unifont Medium* reference (lowercase) in the Mapnik style XML file (e.g., renaming from *unifont Medium* to *Unifont Medium*).

Alternatively, the error might be related to the severity argument *True* currently hard-coded inside some (old) versions of *generate_tiles.py* for `mapnik.load_map`:

```py
mapnik.load_map(self.m, mapfile, True)
```

Depending on how the style is written, it might be needed to edit *generate_tiles.py* and change `mapnik.load_map(self.m, mapfile, True)` to `mapnik.load_map(self.m, mapfile, False)`:

```py
mapnik.load_map(self.m, mapfile, False)
```

This way, fonts with alternative names will generate warnings, not errors; it is appropriate when the style declares fonts with alternative names and expressly needs such Mapnik option, like [OpenStreetMap Carto](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/master/INSTALL.md#additional-deployment-dependencies); also OSMF Servers are configured to set it.

Another way to fix the issue is installing the old *unifont Medium* font, like with this example:

```sh
mkdir -p ~/src ; cd ~/src
mkdir OldUnifont
cd OldUnifont
wget http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/u/unifont/unifont_5.1.20080914.orig.tar.gz
tar xvfz unifont_5.1.20080914.orig.tar.gz unifont-5.1.20080914/font/precompiled/unifont.ttf
sudo cp unifont-5.1.20080914/font/precompiled/unifont.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/unifont/OldUnifont.ttf
sudo fc-cache -fv
fc-list | grep -i unifont # both uppercase and lowercase fonts will be listed
```

Comment: This is not a solution for the problem. It just doesn't terminate XMl creation process, eventually generated XML is useless.

Comment: It might be a solution in certain cases. I updated the answer with additional clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the font name from *unifont Medium* to *Unifont Medium* in inc/fontset-settings.xml.inc file.

Answer (score -1):

`apt-get install unifont` and in `inc/fontset-settings.xml.inc.template` replace `"unifont Medium"` with `"Unifont Medium"`.

Comment: Could you first describe, what your changes should do, and secondly tell us, why you think this is a necessary addition to a 5 years old question?